# Changing the default number of items per page with jQuery pagination?

Tags: jquery, jquery-pagination

I'm using `jquery.dataTables.min.js` for pagination. It shows 10 data in 1 page by default. I want to sort with the page with showing 20, 30 data.

How do I change the number of data shown in a single page?

Comment: waiting for reply .. noone gave :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use some thing like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myTable').dataTable({
                                    "aLengthMenu": [
            [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
        ], 
                                    "iDisplayLength" : 50 
                                });
            } );
```

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
"iDisplayLength" : yourValue
```

suppose you need 25 records to be displayed, then use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"iDisplayLength" : 25
} );
});
```